# Change one letter color in VB Ms Word 2007

Tags: vba, button, textbox, ms-word

I'm new in Visual basic and I would like to approach something simple.

I have <kbd>button</kbd> and `TextBox`

- When I click the button I want to display some string in the textbox, but some particular characters into that string to be in some particular color.

---

**Button:**

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    TextBox1.Text = "Hi my name is Koki"
    End Sub
```

---

**TextBox:**

```
    Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    End Sub
```

**Output:**

[image]

*Note: It will help me even if there is a static solution, something like `<span></span>` in Html*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While dealing with VBA you have to consider ranges and then properties of the given ranges. Here you have a sample code doing what you want:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Set Object = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=10, Top:=10, Width:=80, Height:=80)

    With Object.TextFrame.TextRange
        .Text = "Hi my name is Koki"
        With .Characters(2).Font
            .ColorIndex = wdTurquoise  'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195611(v=office.11).aspx
        End With
        With .Characters(12).Font
            .ColorIndex = wdTurquoise
        End With
        With .Characters(18).Font
            .ColorIndex = wdTurquoise
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

As you can see, I am adding the textbox at the start. I am doing this to make sure that you use the right textBox (if you add an ActiveX textbox the behaviour would be different).

---------- UPDATE

In order to rely on the proposed methodology, you might have to use the Document Open event to delete any shape and write the ones you want. For example:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()

    For i = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).Delete
    Next i

    Set Object = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=10, Top:=10, Width:=80, Height:=80)

End Sub
```

This code will be called when the document is opened and will delete all the shapes you created (not the ActiveX objects, like the commandButton) and add the textbox. You can declare the `Object` variable globally and access it from anywhere in the code (`CommandButton1_Click()`, for example).

Bear in mind that this is an example of a workaround to get what you want. You don't need to delete the given shapes, you can just take this code to check what to do at the start of the document: if there is a shape called "the name I want", let it there and don't do anything, just set it to the global `Object` variable, that is:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()

    For i = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        If(ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).Name = "the name I want") Then
          Set Object = ActiveDocument.Shapes(i)
          Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

    Set Object = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=10, Top:=10, Width:=80, Height:=80)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much..I just want to know if there is a solution where I'll use static frame, not appending frame on every click..I need that because I have two buttons and when i click the first button there will be one text, where i click the second button there will be another text in that same frame, or can you show me the behaviour while using ActiveX textBox. Thanks

Comment: In theory, you should be able to do something equivalent (the commands are different) with the ActiveX control shown in your code, although it is not too reliable (or, at least, I don't know how to make it reliable enough); bear in mind that VBA for Word is not the most reliable programming framework, precisely. You can rely on the OpenDocument event and firstly delete all the shapes and secondly create the ones you want. Let me update my code with this.

Comment: You are welcome. But the accuracy of the statement "all my problems are solved" while dealing with VBA Word tends to be quite low ;)